# What do I need to download to work with SQLite in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I know I need to download some dlls and put them somewhere specific in my Solution folder-hierarchy. I went through tutorials, SQLite.org and system.data.sqlite.org, and I'm still not sure of my needs (at least now I understand what SQLite is, sort of)

I have a x64 machine, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, .NETCore 3.1.200. I would like to code a WPF Desktop application in C# usable on any client machine with the required .NETCore version, so my project is supposed to ship with the SQLite dlls and the database.

I don't know a thing about build commands, project configuration, and similar things (I can't even code a big project in C++ properly because I don't understand the linker).

**TL;DR:**
**My request is:** please send me the download links for the SQLite dlls and tell me where in my solution should they go.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks! I hope people looking for the same answer read your comment. It's a very confusing world, SQLite. People used to code .NET for SQL Server don't even think about stuff like that, it's all ready to go, everything is kind of invisible.

Comment: Most welcome mate. Good luck.